# Deactivate readline autocompletion

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cygwin, readline

I am trying to deactivate the [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline) autocompletion after I have used it. Therefore I want to write a decorator like this:

```
#!python
from contextlib import contextmanager
import readline

def main():
    with readline_autocompletion():
        raw_input('first: ')
    raw_input('second: ')

@contextmanager
def readline_autocompletion():
    readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
    readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n')
    readline.set_completer(None)

    yield

    # How to unload autocompletion without this hack??
    readline.set_completer(no_complete)

def no_complete(text,state):
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to deactivate the readline autocompletion again for the second `raw_input()`?

**EDIT**

I now managed to deactivate the completion by setting a completer that does only return `None` (see code above). Is this ***really*** the way to go in order to deactivate the autocompletion again? Feels like a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After calling `readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')` the TAB is mapped on the function that performs completion. If custom completer is not set the default system file completion is used. There are better solutions than defining custom stub function to change that completion behavior.

The TAB key can insert self (TAB symbol) as before `'tab: complete'` binding:

```
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: self-insert')
```

---

For details take into account that the python readline module is based on the GNU Readline Library ([in case of OS X it may be `libedit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline)). So, the documentation for the library can explain the function `parse_and_bind`. Here the most interesting part is ["Readline Init File"](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9). The function `parse_and_bind` passes its input string as Readline Init File.

It is possible to set values of various variables or bind different functions to keys.

For example there is `disable-completion` variable that should work as `'tab: self-insert'`:

> If set to `On`, Readline will inhibit word completion. Completion
>   characters will be inserted into the line as if they had been mapped
>   to self-insert. The default is `off`.

However, it is not completely true. It can be seen in the current library source code (readline-6.3). If the variable `disable-completion` is set to `on` the `complete` function (binded to `tab`) always inserts symbol of pressed key. However, `self-insert` inserts the symbol only in the `insert` mode. In the `overwrite` mode it overwrites symbol at cursor position. For example, bind to `Ctrl-a` keys the function toggle overwrite mode, `set disable-completion on` and keep `complete` binded to `tab`:

```
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.parse_and_bind('set disable-completion on')
readline.parse_and_bind('C-a: overwrite-mode')
```

At first the tab key works as with `'tab: self-insert'`. However, after pressing `Ctrl-a` the overwrite mode is enabled. Now the tab key still inserts tab symbol, but in case of `self-insert` the tab key overwrites symbols.

Comment: I will be able to test this on monday, thanks for the answer! Do you know where to find some resources how to deal with the readline module? The python docs are not really extensive..

Comment: @Salo I added examples and references. You can see that the most reliable document is the library source code.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your effort. I begin to understand now how this readline module is working ;)